# Using non-ARC static library in ARC project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

OK, this is pretty much what I'm trying to do.

- I've got a HUGE static library full of functions, which has to be NON-ARC (because of errors).
- Now my app *has* to be ARC-enabled.
- However : when ever I'm trying to compile my app, it throws all errors related to my using the NON-arc library.

Any ideas on how this can be solved?

Comment: is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498644/arc-setting-compiler-flags-to-fno-objc-arc-and-build-errors

Comment: The marked duplicate links to a blog post. It's unclear whether the couple sentences in the post are adequate to solve the problem. It would be nice to have an authoritative answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining ARC with MRC is not at all a problem. In fact, you do it every day, as many system frameworks are not implemented using ARC, yet.

So, what are your errors?

Comment: Mainly `ARC Weak References`, `The current deployment target does not support automated __weak references`.

Comment: OK, pretty much a different thing whatsoever. In any case, it's been solved : just by replacing `__weak` references with `__unsafe_unretained`. (Thanks to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893038/how-do-i-replace-weak-references-when-using-arc-and-targeting-ios-4-0)