# Cordova Barcode Reader Compilation Error Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, cordova, barcode-scanner

I am using the [wildabeast barcode reader](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/issues/182) Cordova Plugin to read in some VIN barcodes.

This works fine on Android and on iOS 7 but since updating to Xcode 6 and iOS 8, I am unable to compile the code which processes the barcode. I think it is a configuration issue, but I don't have much experience with iOS or Xcode.

Here is a subset of the errors I am getting:

```
 /platforms/ios/project/Plugins /com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:152:16: 'retain' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins  /com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:152:16: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'retain'
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:153:16: 'retain' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:153:16: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'retain'
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:154:16: 'retain' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:154:16: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'retain'
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:168:75: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:168:75: 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:246:12: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'dealloc'
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:260:118: 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:260:118: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'
 /platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:271:6: 'presentModalViewController:animated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:280:32: 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0
 /platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:287:27: ARC forbids use of 'release' in a @selector
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:324:73: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'
/platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:324:73: 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
 /platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:346:81: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'
 /platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:346:81: 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
 /platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:451:110: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'
 /platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:451:110: 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
 /platforms/ios/project/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm:621:70: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `-fno-objc-arc` into the Build Phases > CompileSources > CDVBarcodeScanner.mm

This article will help [ARC: Setting compiler flags to -fno-objc-arc and build errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498644/arc-setting-compiler-flags-to-fno-objc-arc-and-build-errors)